# Cassandra: Populating a new column in cql

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, cql, cqlsh

I have added a new column to my admin table.I want to populate revision column against effective_date column.

```
        ALTER TABLE prod.admin ADD revision int;
```

The revision number will start with 100 and increment by 1.  The revisions will be based on the effective_date.  So, the oldest effective_date, will get 100, then next oldest will get 101, and so on.

```
          Effective date 1/1/2014 – Revision 100
          Effective date 1/1/2015 – Revision 101
          Effective date 7/1/2015 – Revision 102
          Effective date 1/1/2016 – Revision 103
```

something like below statement??

```
          revision =100
          UPDATE prod.admin 
          SET revision= revision+ 1
          WHERE effective_date = /'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are typically falling in the use-case of data normalization (http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/fast-track-to-getting-started-with-dse-max-ing/66), it's an excellent use-case for **Apache Spark** over **Cassandra**

Plus, you can benefit from data locality for this use-case

Comment: @doanduyhai- Sir, can you a bit explain.. i am very much new to cassandra. it would be great if you can give me an example.Thanks in advance

Comment: Can somebody please help me out , i have no clue whatsoever